# Cauchy product of two formal power series

Tags: power-series, analytic-functions

I am thinking if I could get help for the following question:

Given a formal power series

$$g(z)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i z^{-i}$$

does there always exists another (non-trivial) formal power series $y(z)$, such that the Cauchy product between $y$ and $g$
$$
y \times g= \sum_{i=0}^\infty c_k z^{-k}
$$
satisfies that 
$$
\sum_{i=0}^\infty |c_k| < \infty?
$$

Comment: Would you accept $y = 0$?

Comment: I am seeking for a non-trivial one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the constant term $a_0$ of $g$ is nonzero, then $g$ [will be invertible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Multiplicative_inverse): that is, there is some $y$ such that $y \times g=1$.

If $g$ is nonzero (but we don't make any assumptions about its constant term), let $a_k$ be the first nonzero coefficient of $g$. We then have

\begin{align*}
g(z)&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n\\
&=\sum_{n=k}^\infty a_nz^n&&\text{(because all the prior terms are zero)}\\
&=z^k\sum_{n=k}^\infty a_nz^{n-k}&&\text{(factoring out the common factor of }z^k\text{ from each term)}\\
&=z^k\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n+k}z^n&&\text{(relabeling).}
\end{align*}

The sum in the last line is a power series with nonzero constant term $a_k$. That is, we can write $g=z^kh$, where $h$ is a power series with nonzero constant term. So if we take $y$ to be the multiplicative inverse of $h$, then $y \times g=z^k$.

Finally, if $g=0$, we can take $y$ to be anything we want and have $y \times g=0$.

So, for any power series $g$, we can find $y$ such that $y \times g$ such that finitely many of the $c_k$ (in fact, at most one of the $c_k$!) are nonzero, which means that the sum of their absolute values must converge.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Could you provide a reference for the statement " if g is nonzero g=zkh  for some integer h and invertible power series h". Would nice I can study a bit deeper.

Comment: As another following-up question, for a vector of formal power series as such $[g_1(z) ... g_n(z)]$, do you think there also exists another (scalar) formal power series y(z), such that $y \times [g_1 .... g_n]$ leads to a vector, where every entry (series) satisfies that the coefficients are absolutely summable?

Comment: @ShiJames: I added a proof of that statement. It's not that long. :)

Comment: @ShiJames: I would suggest that you ask your follow-up as a separate question. Off the top of my head, it seems a lot more difficult, though I might be missing something obvious...

Comment: The main step is that with $f(z)=\sum_{k\ge 0} a_k z^k$ if $a_0=1$ then $f(z)^{-1}=\sum_{m\ge 0} (1-f(z))^m$ where the last series converges in the ring of formal power series.

Comment: @Micah: Thanks, it is a firm answer!

Comment: @reuns: by convergence, you mean $f(z)^{-1}$ converge to certain power series?

Comment: @Micah: I've answered that [follow-up question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3695032) (a while ago).