# Cauchy product between a power series and a vector of power series

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, analytic-functions

From [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3694579), it is known that given any formal power series in the following form ($a_0$ may or may not be zero),

$$ g(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k z^k \tag{1} \label{pow-ser} $$

there exists another non-trivial formal power series $y(z)$, such that the Cauchy product between $y(z)$ and $g(z)$

$$ y \times g = \sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k z^{k} $$
satsifies that

$$ \sum_{k=0}^\infty |c_k| < \infty. \tag{2} \label{abs-cvg} $$

A related and probably more complicated problem is as follows:

Given a vector of formal power series in the form of $\eqref{pow-ser}$:

$$P=\begin{bmatrix}
g_1(z) & g_2(z) & \cdots & g_n(z)
\end{bmatrix}$$

does there always exist a non-trivial formal power series $y(z)$, such that every entry of the Cauchy product between $y$ and the vector $P$

$$y \times P$$

satisfies $\eqref{abs-cvg}$?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **negative** already for $\color{blue}{n=2}$, even if we restrict $g_1(z)$ and $g_2(z)$ to represent *functions* of complex variable (analytic near $z=0$). Specifically, we take $\color{blue}{g_1\equiv 1}$, and let $g_2$ be arbitrary for a while. Then $y\times g_1=y$, so the condition $(2)$ implies that $y(z)$ *(represents a function that)* is analytic on $|z|<1$, and so is $y\times g_2$; thus, $g_2(z)$ is *(a restriction of)* a quotient of two functions analytic on $|z|<1$, and any singularity it may have *(there)* must be a pole.

Hence, to build a counterexample, it suffices to take $g_2(z)$ with an essential singularity in $|z|<1$, say $g_2(z)=e^{z/(1-2z)}$. *(Or a branching one, such as $\color{blue}{g_2(z)=\log(1-2z)}$ or $g_2(z)=(1-2z)^{1/2}$.)*